Waited almost a year and a half for a review. The reviewer reviewed the wrong paper. What to do?
Waited almost a year and a half for a review. The reviewer reviewed the wrong paper. What to do? Can I ask the editor to really expedite the next review?

Have you already made the editor aware at least?

@BryanKrause Yes, of course, immediately.

What did they say? Have there been other reviews? I don't think an editor ever tries to have a paper reviewed more slowly than possible. They're mostly waiting for unpaid reviewers that they have no sway over to respond.

While a comment notes, correctly, that the editor has little control over the actions of a reviewer, they most likely have options as to who to send the paper to and some knowledge of how long that person normally takes.
There is no harm in asking. Another option, of course, is to withdraw the paper and submit elsewhere, but there are no guarantees of faster response.
